# SFSafariViewController выдает белый экран

Tags: xcode, swift, safari

Иногда, когда использую SFSafariViewController, он выдает белый экран, блокирующий работу приложения. Это случается с рандомной вероятностью - может как с первого раза выдать, так и с десятого. В методы делегата программа не заходит, никаких ошибок в консоли не выдает. Случается как на симуляторе, так и на реальном устройстве.

Вот такой видок после перехода к SFSafariViewController:
https://monosnap.com/file/FztiBQtP57j63CSNvLgQzZnm6dPP3T

Код:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in

        if let url = URL(string: Defaults[.redirectURL])
        {
            self?.safariController = SFSafariViewController(url: url)
            self?.safariController.delegate = self
            self?.present((self?.safariController)!, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

    }
```

Comment: вы к вопросу добавили скриншот белого экрана?

Comment: предположу, что `DispatchQueue.main.async` при определенных кондициях создает deadlock